# Conditional statement for file_get_contents()

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob, conditional-statements

I am trying to upload pictures when editing forms. However, when I update it without uploading a new picture, it removes the one stored as BLOB in the DB, it works when i upload with a new picture. but when it is blank it fails says file_get_contents cannot be empty and deletes the stored pic(if existing)

```
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['prod_pic']['tmp_name']));
```

If ($image = file_get_contents()) is empty{

nothing will happen, nothing will be deleted and will be ignored
}

else {
upload or replace existing picture.
}

Comment: $_FILES['prod_pic']['tmp_name'] should never need to be escaped using addslashes.

Comment: $image = file_get_contents(); if (!empty($image) { /* upload or replace existing picture */ }

Comment: Also, it's not the subject, but for uploads you should use move_uploaded_file() instead of file_get_contents()

Answer (score 0):

You need to check $_FILES['prod_pic']['error']. It's an integrer that if it is superior to zero, the file couldn't be uploaded. In your case, it's the code error 4 (no file selected).

So you can do

```
if ($_FILES['prod_pic']['error'] == 0)
    // replace current image with uploaded one
```

More informations :http://php.net/manual/fr/features.file-upload.errors.php

You can also check $_FILES['prod_pic']['name'], as it is empty when no file is selected :

```
if (!empty($_FILES['prod_pic']['name'])) // = a file was selected
    // replace current image with uploaded one
```

It is recommanded though to use first option, as the file could be partially uploaded.

Comment: how do i properly use those codes? i have no idea. @whitep4anther

Comment: It's your if condition, you put your code to upload file inside this condition